# Is time spent in elevated heart rate zones due to sensory rather than movement stimulus as beneficial?

Tags: target-heart-rate

There are much touted benefits off for example zone 2 cardio time. In order to achieve this people may do deliberate activities such as rucking.

But I’ve noticed that my heart rate can get elevated simply by riding on my moped, presumably due to the sensory and/or psychological stress of all the traffic and the road’s other hazards whizzing by at such speed, even though the operation of the moped does not require any physiological exertion in itself but just the press of a button. Are such activities as beneficial if they do maintain your header rate in zone 2 as hiking or rucking would also achieve?